# Semi-transparent markers on log-log scatter plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, scatter-plot, markers

I have been trying to get **semi-transparent circle-shape markers** on a **log-log scatter plot**. MATLAB's own `scatter` plot function doesn't produce semi-transparent markers (see comments below), so I am using this wonderful tool `scatter_patches` from [Central File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48157-artemyk-scatter-patches) and it works very well:

However, I am having issues adapting this code for a log-log scatter plot. In order to obtain a log-log scatter plot with this program, I need to fix two things:

1 . Change the axes to log scale. This can be achieved by adding following after line 61:

```
set(cax, 'XScale', 'log'); 
set(cax, 'YScale', 'log');
```

This produces correct log scale and grid points.

2 . However, after I fixed 1., the size of the markers was not uniform in my plot. On a log plot, the lower-value regions of the axes are zoomed-in. In the scatter_patches plot, the markers at the lower side of axes are bigger while they are smaller towards the higher-value side of axes. So, the marker size is not the same on the entire plot. I tried using `log10(cSize)` instead of `cSize` on lines 221-222, but this only slimmed the difference between the largest and smallest marker sizes. It didn't yield the same size markers on the plot.

If anyone has an idea of what I might be missing here, please share.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to use Matlab's scatter plot with `set(hadle_to_scatterplot,'MarkerFaceColor','None')`? It seems like `scatter_patches` create a circle instead of marker.

Comment: I have tried it. Setting 'MarkerFaceColor' to 'None' is equivalent to setting transparency to 100%. However, I want to control the transparency. If a property like 'MarkerFaceAlphaValue' existed, then I could have set transparency to arbitrary values. But such a property doesn't exist. The scatter_patches uses patches in place of markers; so a FaceAlphaValue can be set. This program also allows creation of other shapes, not just circles. The program works very well on linear plots. It is the log plot where some changes are required.

Comment: I think that this [article](http://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/263990-how-to-draw-a-circle-in-a-log-log-plot) will interest you. Have you try to add an `exp()`here:         `set(patchObjects(i), 'XData', cSize * sin(patchSpec) / ptsPerXUnit + xs(i));
        set(patchObjects(i), 'YData', cSize * cos(patchSpec) / ptsPerYUnit + ys(i));`like `set(patchObjects(i), 'XData', cSize * exp(sin(patchSpec))/ ptsPerXUnit + xs(i));` But i didn't tried !

Comment: Ups: more like this: `set(patchObjects(i), 'XData', exp(cSize * sin(patchSpec)/ ptsPerXUnit + xs(i)));` and the same for YData

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since **Matlab R2014b** things got really easy. No additional functions from file exchange are required, just some [**undocumented features**](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/plot-markers-transparency-and-color-gradient). The basic idea is to get the hidden handle of the markers and apply a value **< 1** for the last value in the `EdgeColorData` to achieve the desired transparency.

Here we go:

```
%// example data
x = linspace(0,3*pi,200);
y = cos(x) + rand(1,200);

%// plot scatter, get handle
h = scatter(x,y); 
drawnow; %// important

%// get marker handle
hMarkers = h.MarkerHandle; 

%// get current edge and face color
edgeColor = hMarkers.EdgeColorData
faceColor = hMarkers.FaceColorData

%// set face color to the same as edge color
faceColor = edgeColor;

%// opacity
opa = 0.3;

%// set marker edge and face color
hMarkers.EdgeColorData = uint8( [edgeColor(1:3); 255*opa] ); 
hMarkers.FaceColorData = uint8( [faceColor(1:3); 255*opa] );
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this one. But this seem to affect the transparency of the edges only, not the face of the marker.

Comment: To be sure, your approach changes `hMarkers.EdgeColorData` dimension from `1x1x3` to `1x1x4` with 'layers' representing channels Red, Green, Blue and Opacity, respectively? In other words, can one suppose that `uint8` array with size of `M x N x 4` represents texture map with width of M pixels, height of N pixels with defined colour and poacity of each pixel?

Comment: @user164568 I have MATLAB 2011b, so I cannot try. Have you tried to use `hMarkers.FaceColorData` instead?

Comment: @Crowley yes, exactly.

Comment: @user164568 of course not, for that you need the FaceColorData property. Have a look at my edit.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Your edit worked like a charm! Thank you so much! This also works well on log plots. Fortunately, I have MATLAB 2015a.

Comment: @Crowley For MATLAB 2011b, I think only some fix on scatter_patches can work.

Comment: @user164568 I know that. I've mentioned it to imply that I think the change in code might work and not that I assure that it will work. thewaywewalk approved that.

Comment: @thewaywewalk There still seems to be one issue. When I enlarge the marker size to 80 (from the default), it shows a dot in the center of the circular marker. Is it possible to get rid of the dots?

Comment: @user164568 I can't reproduce your problem, please post a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

In the event it helps, I have written a collection of Matlab functions for creating semi-transparent markers in plots and legends. The files are available from MATLAB Central as the [MarkerTransparency](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/65194-peterrochford-markertransparency) package. A few examples of how to use these functions are included in the download and there is also a Wiki on [GitHub](http://github.com/PeterRochford/MarkerTransparency/wiki). A major benefit of this package is it enables the user to have the semi-transparent markers also appear in the legend. These functions have not been tested for scatter plots but might be easily adapted to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

On line 192 change the line with this one:

`hh(end+1) = patch( exp(cSize * sin(patchSpec) / ptsPerXUnit + xs(i)), exp(cSize * cos(patchSpec) / ptsPerYUnit + ys(i)), cColor, cPatchArgs{:});` and it will work.

I just add an `exp()`

Do the same operation on line 222 and 223 to be sure !

Work like a charm Anindya ;).

Comment: My plot is on log10 scale. So I used `hh(end+1) = patch( 10.^((cSize * sin(patchSpec) / ptsPerXUnit + xs(i))./10), 10.^((cSize * cos(patchSpec) / ptsPerYUnit + ys(i))./10), cColor, cPatchArgs{:});` This certainly produces circles of same size. However, my plot doesn't look the same as the one produced by MATLAB's scatterplot function. See here: http://imgur.com/21yM6hY